# Counting all nodes in a tree

Tags: c++, count, binary-tree

This is my current code. It works fine, but I can't figure out a way to add the root node to the count because it always gets added a bunch of times due to the program being recursive.

```
int countTree(tnode<T> *t)
{

int count = 0;


 if (t != NULL)
 {
     count = count + countTree(t->left);

if (t->left)
    { count++; }

  count = count + countTree(t->right);

if (t->right)
    { count++; }
}


return count;

};
```

Answer (score 3):

The usual recursion for node count in a binary tree is `1 + count(left sub-tree) + count(right sub-tree)`, where `count(null)` returns 0.

So it would be something like:

```
int count(node *root)
{
    if (!root) { return 0; }

    return 1 + count(root->left) + count(root->right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
int countTree(tnode<T> *t)
{  
 if (t==NULL)
    return 0;
 return 1+countTree(t->left)+countTree(t-right);
}
```

Comment: The variable `count ` isn't used at all

Comment: You call both `countTree` and `countRight`. And I believe `NULL` isn't idiomatic C++

Comment: silly mistakes... NULL is a macro defined in cstring header file. check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/NULL/) and many other headers..

Comment: Got confused about `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Or **how to iterate a tree** while calling a method on each node only once.

It depends on your tree implementation, here is an example tree based on  `boost::intrusive` data struct and algorithms (with a fix not yet published in `boost`). The main points are:

- the `header` node (root) is not part of the tree, it's left node points to the first node, last node points to he last item and header node itself is the end iterator node
- next node is returned by `next()` which returns the next node in order - when it gets to the bottom (3 in the example) it goes back up to the top and then finds the next `minimum()` node (5 in this case).

example code

```
#include <iostream>

struct node {
    int value;

    node * left;
    node * right;
    node * parent;

    node( int v )
        : value( v )
        , left( nullptr )
        , right( nullptr )
        , parent( nullptr )
    {}

    node() : node( 0 ) {}
    ~node() {}
};
```

to print node:

```
std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, const node * n ) {
    return os << ( n ? n->value : 0 );
}
```

to iterate:

```
node * minimum( node * n ) {
    for ( node * l = n->left; l; l = n->left ) n = l;
    return n;
}

node * maximum( node * n ) {
    for ( node * r = n->right; r; r = n->right) n = r;
    return n;
}

node * next( node * n ) {
    if ( ! n ) return nullptr;
    if ( n->right ) return minimum( n->right );
    node * p = n;
    node * x = p->parent;
    while ( p == x->right ) {
        p = x;
        x = x->parent;
    }
    return p->right != x ? x : p;
}

node * prev( node * n ) {
    if ( ! n ) return nullptr;
    if ( n->left ) return maximum( n->left );
    node * p = n;
    node * x = p->parent;
    while ( p == x->left ) {
        p = x;
        x = x->parent;
    }
    return p->left != x ? x : p;
}
```

simple iterator uses `next()` which figures out what to visit next:

```
void iterate( node * root, void(*func)( node * n ) ) {

    node * n = root->left;
    node * e = root;

    while ( n != e and n ) {
        func( n );
        n = next( n );
    }
}
```

use this to count:

```
static void counter( node * n ) {
    static uint count( 0 );
    ++count;
    std::cout << count << " node [" << n  << "]" << std::endl;
}
```

Tree would look like this:

```
/*
 * a binary tree
 * for each node, left nodes are smaller, right nodes are bigger
 *
 * header node is just a header node, not part of a tree
 * header.left points to the "first node" in example below to 3
 * header.right points to the "last node" in the example below 2
 * end iterator is the header itself
 * header node is not part of a tree
 *

  --------  R ------
  |         |      |
  |         4      |
  |       /   \    |
  |     2      5 < +
  |    /  \
  +> 1     3
*/
```

create the tree manually - you would use `boost::intrusive` instead of this code anyway ...

```
void test() {
    node r( 999 );

    node n1( 1 );
    node n2( 2 );
    node n3( 3 );
    node n4( 4 );
    node n5( 5 );

    // setup n2
    n2.left = & n1;
    n2.right = & n3;

    n1.parent = & n2;
    n3.parent = & n2;

    // setup n4

    n4.left = & n2;
    n2.parent = & n4;

    n4.right = & n5;
    n5.parent = & n4;
    n4.parent = & r;

    // setup header node - header not part of a tree

    r.left = & n1;
    r.right = & n5;

    iterate( & r, & counter );
}
```

run

```
int main() {
    test();
}
```

result:

```
1 node [1]
2 node [2]
3 node [3]
4 node [4]
5 node [5]
```

Each node accounted for and header node not included.
Not sure if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a function that wraps around countTree and adds 1 if the first node is not null.

For example,

```
int BaseCountFunc(tnode<T> *t)
{
    int returnValue;

    returnValue = 0;

    if (t!=nullptr)
    {
        returnValue = 1 + countTree(t->left) + countRight(t->right);
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```